# How to select a field as input value in a CRM 2011 custom workflow activity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-activity

I need the end user to select which field he wants updated. Is there an option to have a lookup input parameter that let's the user select a field of the current entity?

I need it to perform operations on the value of the selected field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a custom type to handle a list of fields (or a list of strings) as `InputParameter` for a Custom Workflow Activity.

The (ugly) alternative is to use a string parameter where the user enters the field name.

Comment: The ugly solution is usable by dev's, but an end-user will not be so forgiving...

Comment: Selected as correct answer, because it is indeed not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the list of fields isn't very big, you could add an optionset to the form with those field names and then your workflow could have `If` conditions based on that optionset.

Comment: Good solution for entities that don't change much. Else you need to update it all the time. And you run the risk that power-users put it on a form or view.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to use a dialog to complete this. You can set the stage, the parameter and based on the situation the values to insert. Also you can execute workflows from the dialog itself.

Comment: I don't understand why you suggest a dialog since it has the exact same restrictions as a workflow.

Comment: Well i thought you were asking how to pass a different field on a form to a workflow, based on the user choices. With the conditions in a dialog you can point the workflow in the right direction. If the problem is that with the dialog there are too many steps, then my bad.

Answer (score -1):

If the record already exists, consider registering a plug-in on the update message. When in update the request InputParameter["Target"] contains only dirty fields changed by the user.

Instead of creating a list of fields you can create another (role) form to limit the fields the user can edit on the form.